# Volley is not showing the data in the RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I am trying to get data from a JSON File using volley method and show it in RecyclerView but its not showing any data on RecyclerView. mysql Databse is configured on xampp. Code is below.
I am new to android so you have to give your answers in detail.

Here is my PHP file getdata.php:

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root" , "", "recycleview_volley");


$query = "SELECT * FROM image_data";
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
$recycler_data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $recycler_data [] = array(
   'image_url'     => $row["image_url"],
   'image_name'    => $row["image_name"]


    );

}
echo json_encode($recycler_data);
```

my MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.razaz.recyclerviewpractice;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

private RequestQueue mQueue;

private ArrayList<String> mNames = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> mImageUrls = new ArrayList<>();
public String url = "";




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: started.");


    mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);




    getData();
    initRecyclerView();



}



    private void initRecyclerView(){
        Log.d(TAG, "initRecyclerView: init recyclerView.");


        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, mNames, mImageUrls);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }

    public void getData(){
        url = "http://127.0.0.1/recycler_api/getdata.php";


        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        try {

                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                mImageUrls.add(jsonObject.getString("image_url"));
                                mNames.add(jsonObject.getString("image_name"));



                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                },new Response.ErrorListener(){
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                error.getStackTrace();

            }


        });



        mQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }

}
```

my RecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
package com.example.razaz.recyclerviewpractice;

import android.content.Context;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    private static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewAdapter";

    ArrayList<String> mImagesNames = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> mImages = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context mContext;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> mImagesNames, ArrayList<String> mImages) {
        this.mImagesNames = mImagesNames;
        this.mImages = mImages;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder( ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_listitem, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder( ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: called.");

        Glide.with(mContext)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(mImages.get(position))
                .into(viewHolder.image) ;

        viewHolder.imageName.setText(mImagesNames.get(position));
        viewHolder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Clicked on: "+ mImages.get(position));

                Toast.makeText(mContext, mImagesNames.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mImagesNames.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        CircleImageView image;
        TextView imageName;
        RelativeLayout parentLayout;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            imageName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_name);
            parentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
        }
    }
}
```

I think there is a bug in volley.

Comment: Volley doesn't work ready-made, you have to call setDataChange() after getting a successful response. You have initialized it with new, and that is the list you are passing. How will it reflect according to your list?

Comment: 1) Call _recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));_ before set adapter. 2) Populate your adapter in _onResponse()_ method 3) Check your list size. 4) Must be sure that it should not be local URL.

Comment: the easy way for you is to move `initRecyclerView();` after the for loop inside `onResponse`

Comment: @Raza Zaidi Can you post your activity code where you are calling setAdapter() method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Adapter class write:

```
private ArrayList<String> mImageList;
public void setDataChange(ArrayList<String> imageList) {
    mImageList = new ArrayList<>(imageList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Call this method after getting successful result on Volley response method that is inside `onResponse()`.
Parse the result as per your `List<String>`, Create a list and add it into your global list and call:

`adapter.setDataChange(imageList);`

Or another way:

1. Create pojo of imageUrl and imageName;
2. `private List<PojoClass> imageList;`

After getting result in onResponse(),
do like this:

```
imageList =new List<PojoClass>;

PojoClass pojo=new PojoClass();
pojo.setImageUrl(imageUrl);
pojo.setImageName(imageName);

imageList.add(pojo);
```

pass it over adapter like this:

`adapter.setDataChange(imageList);`

Comment: I am new to android so I failed to implement your method. what so ever I tried to debug it by longing each method and it seems onResponse method is not calling. Still trying to figure out the problem there.

Comment: Check my another answer that I am adding in this question, That is the detailed stepwise guide for your code. After that descriptive answer, no one can explain your word to word, You need to read tutorials. We can just give you direction.

Comment: @StutiKasliwal Could you give me a handed on volley-related question?

Answer (score 3):

**In Listener:**
   Make an Interface or Listener as:

```
public interface OnRowItemClick {
    void onClick(int position, PojoClass pojo);
}
```

**In Adpter class:**

1. declare click listener object:

   ```
   private OnRowItemClick mOnRowItemClick;
   private List<PojoClass> imageList;
   ```
2. get the object in constructor of adapter:

   ```
   public HomeCategoriesAdapter(Context mContext, OnRowItemClick mOnRowItemClick,
                            ArrayList<PojoClass> imageArrayList) {
   this.mContext = mContext;
   this.mOnItemClickListener = mOnItemClickListener;
   this.imageList = imageArrayList;
   ```

   }
3. In bindView method, where you set your details:

   ```
   PojoClass pojo = imageList.get(position);
   viewHolder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           mOnItemClickListener.onClick(position, pojo);
       }
   });
   ```

**In MainActivity:**

1. Declare your adapter class:

   ```
     private List<PojoClass> imageList;
     private MyItemAdapter myItemAdapter;
   ```
2. Initialize your adapter class:

   ```
     List<YourModel> modelItemList;
     modelItemList = new ArrayList<>();
     myItemAdapter = new MyItemAdapter(mContext, this, modelItemList);
     recyclerView.setAdapter(myItemAdapter);
   ```

After Service Call:

```
   imageList =new List<PojoClass>;

   PojoClass pojo=new PojoClass();
   pojo.setImageUrl(imageUrl);
   pojo.setImageName(imageName);
   imageList.add(pojo);
   adapter.setDataChange(imageList);
```

Comment: @Raza Zaidi , go through with this code, I have made it more descriptive as I can.