# Why when I use setClickable(true) it's not show the action of click

Tags: android, android-studio, onclicklistener

Actually, I use a ListView and when I use `setClickable(false)` I have the animation as if I clicked on a button you see? The animation that shows you click. Which is not normal, I think, basic.

And when I use `setClickable(true)` I no longer have the animation, as well as if I use

```
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
```

And i would like to use the `OnClickListener` but I think it would be better for the user to see that he can click, so to have the animation when you click.

So, I'd like to see when the user clicks on an item in the list, it does the action I want (I'll add that later) but let's imagine a Toast but it displays the effect as if you click on a button. The effect i got if i use `setClickable(false)` (the default setting).

**That's the ripple effect !**

Comment: what you want to do actually ?

Comment: Sorry, actually I'd like to see when the user clicks on an item in the list, it does the action I want (I'll add that later) but let's imagine a Toast but it displays the effect as if you click on a button. Do you see ?

Comment: ripple effect you mean?

Comment: Go through with this answer once, if this is your requirement as per my understanding. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53959232/7612991

Comment: Yes that's the word ! Ripple effect thanks ! So you know how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the row's layout of the ListView just add:

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

This will add the Ripple effect. If you want to show it on top of the other views, use the forground attribute:

```
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

Answer (score 3):

add this `foreground:?attr/selectableItemBackground` to your view attribute, it should work